# Video Recording in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, recording

I need xcode sample program to record video in iphone 3G ios 4.2.

I downloaded another app that is running fine.

**There is another way by using AVFoundation framework. Anyone has idea about this.**

Please reply ASAP.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt the video capture mode is available in iPhone 3G.Its available from iPhone 3GS

Answer (score 0):

I am sure now that Video Capturing is not avilable in iPhone 3G.It is available from iPhone 3GS and further.

Cheers

Comment: There are apps available on app store that are running on iPhone 3G. I tested them. May be using default code it is not possible but we can record video on 3G also.

Comment: Hi All, Please provide a solution ASAP. Its urgent.